# todo list how to properly add delete function in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have created a Vue3 to-do list project with VueCLI(VueX) for practice. I can add items to the array of objects and display them from objects.

Now, I want to implement a delete function that when I click the delete button beside the item, it deletes the element and also removes the object from array.
Here is my code:

NoteInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="inputValue"
      @keyup.enter="addItem"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export default {
  setup() {
    const inputValue = ref()
    const store = useStore()
    const addItem = () => {
      if (inputValue.value !== '') {
        store.commit('addItem', inputValue.value)
      }
      inputValue.value = ''
    }
    return {
      inputValue,
      addItem
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

NoteItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in list"
      :key="index"
    >
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <span>
      <button @click="deleteItem">Delete</button>
    </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    const list = store.state.list
    const deleteItem = () => {
      // store.commit('deleteItem', this.item.title)
      console.log()
    }
    return {
      list,
      deleteItem
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

store/index.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    list: []
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
    addItem(state, item) {
      state.list.push({
        title: item,
        status: 'normal'
      })
    },
    deleteItem(state, item) {
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you want to map the delete key to delete the element or are you willing to add a separate button for the delete action? If you want to map the key, you might as well try using a vanilla JS eventListener

Comment: @PushpakRuhil I currently have a delete button on the right side of every item in the list. I wanted to achieve that when I click the delete button, it removes the corresponding div tag as well as the object in the array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please modify your NoteItem.vue and store/index.js files as below.
Working codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vuex-4-vue-router-forked-ei4x1r

NoteItem.vue

```
<template>
<div>
<div
  v-for="(item, index) in list"
  :key="index"
>
<span>{{item.title}}</span>
<span>
  <button @click="deleteItem(index)">Delete</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export default {
setup() {
 const store = useStore()
 const list = store.state.list
 const deleteItem = () => {
  store.commit('deleteItem', index)
 }
 return {
  list,
  deleteItem
 }
 }
}
</script>
```

store/index.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
state: {
list: []
},
getters: {
},
mutations: {
addItem(state, item) {
  state.list.push({
    title: item,
    status: 'normal'
  })
},
deleteItem(state, index) {
  state = state.list.splice(index, 1);
}
},
actions: {
},
modules: {
}
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks clear and simple by following your logic in the link.